# How to get inline-block to work with sub submenu HTML list

Tags: css, xhtml, html-lists

I have an annoying problem, my li's dont want to display side by side with a padding of 10px between them.

when i add a submenu with a submenu the li's dont want to inline-block. Here is an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/3EQPU/3/

Hover on diving and the 2 sub menu items are NOT inline-block..

Why is this? Can you help?

Comment: Clean up your code. Its a mess.

Comment: Solved the problem. Code isnt a mess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

```
clear:both;
```

in

```
#new-menu-lower ul li ul li
```